# Passing Table Name as parameter in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I created a SQL Server procedure where I am passing table names as parameters.

```
@Input_Table_Name nvarchar(200),
@Output_Table_Name nvarchar(200)
```

This is working fine when I use `select * from @Input_Table_Name`, however it's not working when I use `select * into @Output_Table_Name` or `Update @Output_Table_Name` or `Alter table @Output_Table_Name`.

I understand creating a dynamic query instead of passing table name as parameter is a good practice, however in this case, I just want to work with passing table name as parameter.

Please let me know how we can make this work with `Select * into`, `Alter Table`, or `Update` SQL statements.

Comment: You'll need to build and execute a dynamic SQL string using the parameter value. See [this article](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Cre_tbl).

Comment: `select * from @Input_Table_Name` works with `@Input_Table_Name nvarchar(200)`?!

Comment: is there a way other than creating a dynamic SQL

Comment: @Siddharth SQL Server is declarative by design and does not support macro substitution.  If you must... dynamic is your only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments the only way to make it pure T-SQL is to use dynamic SQL. But if you enable [SQLCMD mode in SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/scripting/edit-sqlcmd-scripts-with-query-editor) you could write something like:

```
:setvar TableName "myTableName"
GO

SELECT * FROM $(TableName);
--it will be executed as: SELECT * FROM myTableName
```